# Trigger an function before child window loads in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using `window.open('child.html')` function, and the child window has to load some data from server. When child window opens, till that data loading from server, child window URL shows about:blank and window will be blank till data loads. I want to show some loading image in that child window. How to handle that child window blank time? Looking for solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put a loading image in `child.html` which gets replaced when the AJAX request completes. Also make sure that you're not using `async: false` as that will stop the UI updating while the request is being processed

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sounds like it's not an ajax request, but a simple "open html page that takes time".  If that's the case, then refactor to make it an ajax call and do what Rory suggested (or, if it's ajax, consider not even opening the window until the ajax has completed and show a progress indicator directly on the page)

Comment: @freedomn-m you're right. For some reason I assumed OP was using AJAX already.